# Display system back button on SwiftUI NavigationView with no previous NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a custom SwiftUI title view, which consists of several `Text`s and an `Image` (the `Image` is left out for simplification). The SwiftUI view with the title view is being presented from a `UIViewController`, hence I need a custom back button that navigates back from the `View` (that's being displayed in a `UIHostingController`) to the previous `UIViewController` that presented it.

I want this custom back button to look exactly like the system back button, however, I cannot find the right system image for it. I've tried `Image(systemName: "chevron.left")` and also `Text("❮")` (along with pretty much all other system images and unicode arrow chars), but none of these provide the look of the system back button.

Is there any way to match the look of the system back button in SwiftUI?

This is what the system back button looks like (the trailing button is a Unicode left arrow, the leading button is the system back button):
[image: system back button]

And my custom back button (as you can see, it's much smaller than the system one):
[image]

TitleView.swift:

```swift
class TitleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let backAction: () -> ()
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var subtitle: String?

    init(name: String, subtitle: String?, backAction: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.name = name
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.backAction = backAction
    }
}

struct TitleView: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TitleViewModel

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    content
                        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                        .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination").navigationBarItems(trailing: Text("❮")), label: { Text("Next")
                    })
                }
            }
            titleView
        }
    }

    private var backButton: some View {
        Button(action: viewModel.backAction) { Image(systemName: "chevron.left") }
    }

    private var titleView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.name)
            Text(viewModel.subtitle ?? "")
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func titleView(_ viewModel: TitleViewModel) -> some View {
        modifier(TitleView(viewModel: viewModel))
    }
}
```

DetailsView.swift

```swift
public struct DetailsView: View {
    public var backAction: () -> ()

    public var body: some View {
        Text("Text")
            .titleView(TitleViewModel(name: "Title", subtitle: "SubTitle", backAction: backAction))
    }
}

public class DetailsViewController: UIHostingController<DetailsView> {
    public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
}

public struct RootView: View {
    public var next: () -> ()

    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Root")
            Button(action: next, label: { Text("Next") })
        }
    }
}
```

And in `SceneDelegate`, set up a `UINavigationController` that presents a `UIHostingController` as the `rootViewController`

```swift
func instantiateRootViewController() -> UIViewController {
    let navigationController = UINavigationController()
    let detailsView = DetailsView(backAction: { navigationController.popViewController(animated: true) })
    let presentDetailsView = { navigationController.pushViewController(DetailsViewController(rootView: detailsView), animated: true) }
    let rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: RootView(next: presentDetailsView))
    navigationController.pushViewController(rootViewController, animated: true)
    return navigationController
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let rootViewController = instantiateRootViewController()
        window.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
private var backButton: some View {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
            .scaleEffect(0.83)
            .font(Font.title.weight(.medium))
    }
}
```

Optionally you can apply `.offset` as well, but this may not adapt properly for larger accessibility font sizes:

```
.offset(x: -7, y: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this still is slightly off the system design, but I'll play around with `.font` to try to more closely match it. I didn't realise you can apply a `Font` modifier to an `Image` as well, good to know.

Comment: @DávidPásztor You're welcome, if you find a closer match please let me know.

Comment: Changing `Weight` to `.medium` is as far as I managed to get, it's still not 100% there, but I'd say pretty close enough so that users wouldn't notice the difference unless they're looking at a system back button and the custom back button at the same time :)